# Panda Dataframe to SQL error : Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 5 supplied

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I've taken some data from html using beautiful soup and created a panda dataframe. I'm now trying to export this dataframe into a 3 column table in sqlite. Columns in my table are (panda_no, Title, Year).

The python code to create the dataframe works as  as I would hope

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('films.sqlite')

html_pages = ['table - 3.html']

for page in html_pages:

    with open(page, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")

        titles = soup.find_all("td", {"width": "41%"}, string=re.compile(r'^(?!Title$)'))

        titles_list = [each.text for each in titles ]
        years = soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^\d{4}$'))
        year_list = [each.text for each in years ]
        # d is a dctionary
        d = {'Title':titles_list, 'Year':year_list}

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        print(df)
```

The dataframe looks like this.

```
          Title  Year
0  Quatermass 2  1957
1  Ghostbusters  1985
```

However my code to insert the datafarme into an sqllite table table(test) as follows

```
   stmt = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?, ? )"
   con.executemany(stmt, df)
```

Error I'm getting is

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 5 supplied
```

Can anyone kindly help with this error please? I believe the 3 bindings in the statement are (?, ?, ? ) in the the INSERT statement. However I don't understand why there are 5 bindings I'm attempting to insert. many thanks

Comment: Just a guess: Perhaps you have some embedded commas/quotes in the data that are not being escaped correctly.

Comment: Can you try replacing your `stmt` variable with `stmt = '''INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?, ? )'''` . It just replaces the `" "` symbols with three ` '  ' ` instead as seen from the examples [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/insert/)